# Carrierwave extension_white_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

New to Rails and Carrierwave and trying to setup the extension white list. This is what I have in my attachment_uploader.rb controller:

```
    class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

      ...

      # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
      def extension_white_list
         %w(pdf)    
      end

      ...

    end
```

The validation is working. When someone uploads an attachment that is not a pdf, the form will provide an error message. However, a minor annoyance is that the validation error message is: Attachment You are not allowed to upload "txt" files, allowed types: pdf".

How do I make it so that the word "Attachment" is removed from the beginning of the error message?

In addition, I have another validation to ensure that the attachment is not blank.

```
     validates_presence_of :attachment, :on=> :create
```

However, if an incorrect file is uploaded, it triggers both the extension validation error and  the blank file validation error. How can I only trigger the file extension error in these cases and not both errors?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, that's a default behaviour in Rails, when you call `object.errors.full_messages`. You could build yours from the `object.errors.messages` hash, in your case, this should look like:

```
{attachment: ['You are not allowed to upload "txt" files, allowed types: pdf"']}
```

OR

[Look at this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#i18n), in order to customize the error message